# hide id value in a autocomplete list

Tags: jquery

I have tried to make a auto-complete list that shows the names of companies drawn from a database on a form. It all works well except that the only way I can pass the data through the form is by having its index number displayed as well. How do I hide the number and only show the name of the company.

I am very new to this so apologies in advance.

**HTML input,**

```
<td width="20%"><h2>Supplied By</h2></td>
<td width="30%">
<input type="text" class="autosuggest" name="supplierID"  id="supplierID"> 
<div class="dropdown">
<ul class="result" value="supplierID"></ul>
</div>
script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/primary.js"></script>
</td>
```

**js/primary.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.autosuggest').keyup(function(){
        var search_term = $(this).attr('value');
        $.post('../ajax/position.php', {search_term:search_term},      function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
            $('.result li').click(function() {
                var result_value = $(this).text();
                $('.autosuggest').attr('value', result_value);
                $('.result').html('');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

***../ajax/position.php***

```
<?php
   require_once '../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php';
if (isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false) 
{
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['search_term']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `Company` , `CompanyID` FROM `company`
    WHERE `Company`
    LIKE '$search_term%'");
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !==false) 
    {
        echo '<li>',$row['CompanyID'].$row['Company'],'</li>';
    }
}   
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi G-Nugget what does it mean by you editing something?

Comment: G-Nugget edited your post, and made some changes on your behalf. To see what he did click the `time ago` above his name.

Answer (score 2):

You must having this Company ID as id for the 'li' for example.

```
<?php
   require_once '../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php';
if (isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false) 
{
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['search_term']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `Company` , `CompanyID` FROM `company`
    WHERE `Company`
    LIKE '$search_term%'");
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !==false) 
    {
        echo '<li id='$row["CompanyID"]'>'.$row['Company'].'</li>';
    }
}   
    ?>
```

and use the 'li' id when you want to pass to the server

Comment: Hi muthu thanks for your prompt reply, while I am sure you know what you are doing I couldn't get it to work. When I replaced the code you provided it wouldn't show anything in the list.

Comment: Hi please replace the content in while loop with echo '<li id='.$row["CompanyID"].'>'.$row["Company"].'</li>'; and make sure that whether it's printing

Comment: OK so I replaced the code in the while loop as you suggested and the index number disappeared as requested. Problem is it isn't being carried through to the form. When I changed it to echo '<li  id='.$row["CompanyID"].'>'.$row["CompanyID"].'</li>'; and started typing the ID numbers came up in the list and when i tried posting it it worked except it not what i want obviously.